# How to change default_controller URI Routing in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to change default controller URI Routing Codeigniter to this here is my code :

from->

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

to->

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home_controller/home';
```

with this I have store class Home_controller in folder controller/public

thank for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know and understand why you use the folder `public` inside the folder of `controllers` and i strongly disagree with that if you don't know the purpose of this.

In this case you should change your `base_url` in `application/config/config.php` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://YOUR_DOMAIN/public/';
```

Otherwise, try to set your route as:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'public/Home_controller/home';
```

If you definitely need the `public` folder inside `controllers`, because you have another folder inside `controllers`, comment me and i will suggest you another generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes):

> You can NOT use a directory as a part of this setting!

Instead, if it can fit your requirements, you can set default controller in `controllers` directory like `Home.php` and put redirection in `index` method to your wanted route.